# how to solve "Fatal error version incompatibility" in Source Guardian?

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, xampp, fatal-error

im using "Xampp" currently as LocalHost for wordpress, some themes and Plugins need Source Guardian loader to work.
this is what i did as instructions:

1. Installed "ixed.7.4ts.win" (version 7.4ts of sourceguardian) in Xammp >> php >> ext
2. Inserted this line of code "extension=ixed.7.4ts.win" in **php.ini** ( in line 967, after some extension codes ) and reset everything.

this is what i get now:
**Fatal error: SourceGuardian Loader - This protected script was not encoded for version 7.4.5 of PHP. Please re-encode or contact the author of the script regarding this problem**
what should i do !?

Comment: Did you solve this?

Comment: Did you get the solution for this ? If so, please share it here. I am also facing the same problem.

Comment: @phpfresher no sadly.

Comment: @Rahmani nope... .